# I am getting AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type. in video tag mp4 in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-video

```
    My code is

     <video width="300" preload="auto" height="200" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
      <source src="https://pulseway.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/website/Mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>                           
     </video>

I am getting AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type. in video tag mp4.Can anyone help me fix this problem IN IE 11
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLdf9acy/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "ogg" file type also, like

For that you have to convert your video into "ogg" type.

Comment: I got solution and it is without ogg type.

Answer (score 0):

Video is high in size and i converted into small now it is working.